# Invalid property assignment: "displayText" is a read-only property in TextField qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've got this error in qml and I don't know how to handle it. please help me.
here is my code:

```
StyledTextField {

                readOnly: false
                id: sceneNameField


                anchors.margins: 4
                displayText:"sa"

//                placeholderText: "sasasaaaa"

                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhUrlCharactersOnly
                implicitWidth: parent.width
                selectByMouse: true




            }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? a default value?

Comment: @ynos  yes. Exactly

Answer (score 4):

As per Qt documentation [displayText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#displayText-prop) is read-only.
It would have the same value as `text` when [echoMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#echoMode-prop) is `TextInput.Normal`
So you can simply set the `text` property.

```
StyledTextField {
                id: sceneNameField
                readOnly: false
                anchors.margins: 4

                text:"sa"

                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhUrlCharactersOnly
                implicitWidth: parent.width
                selectByMouse: true
            }
```

Comment: This one doesn't work either. I copied the exact code you suggested .

Comment: Here is another problem: I used the id of this field in some other places to get the text. When I change the id  of styledTextField , it works correctly and shows the default value. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @mahyarsadeghi, I don't get the point. you can use the id just in the same file

Comment: Thanks. Actually the problem is solved. I had changed  the text to empty somewhere .

Comment: @mahyarsadeghi If that solves your problem, then kindly mark this answer as accepted, as it will be helpful for future readers to identify the working solutions quickly rather than going through all the comments under all submitted answers. Hope you understand my point.